# How to place a symbol to the right of the last item

Tags: latex

I have created an environment and I want to put a symbol (`$\circ$`) to the right of the last item of an itemize, which is inside the environment. However, using `\hspace*{\fill}$\circ$` places `$\circ$` at the end of the next line (after the last item). How can I fix this?

Here is the code of the environment:

```
\newenvironment{algoritmo}[3]
{
\setitemize     {labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*, labelsep=1em, itemindent=0em, rightmargin=0em, 
topsep=0em, parsep=0em, partopsep=0em, itemsep=0em}
\setenumerate   {labelindent=\parindent, leftmargin=*, labelsep=1em, itemindent=0em, rightmargin=0em, 
topsep=0em, parsep=0em, partopsep=0em, itemsep=0em}
\begin{Alg}[#2]
\label{#1}
\normalsize
\rmfamily
\itshape
``#3''
\vspace{1ex}
}
{ 
\hspace*{\fill}$\circ$
\end{Alg}
}
```

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: unrelated: don't abuse math mode for multi-letter words, this messes up the kerning

Comment: \documentclass {article}
\usepackage {amssymb}
\begin {document}
\begin {itemize}
\item nono nono nonon nono nono nono nono nono nono
\item nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono  
\item nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono nono
\end {itemize}
\hspace{\fill}$\square$
\end {document}

Comment: I would like the square to appear to the right of the last item, in the same line as it.

Comment: Hey hi! What is `\begin{Alg}[#2]`?